# How to install OpenTSDB on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: java, installation, opentsdb

I try to install OpenTSDB 2.4 locally.
Environment:

- ubuntu 20.04
- openjdk 16.0.1 2021-04-20
- OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 16.0.1+9-Ubuntu-120.04)
- OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 16.0.1+9-Ubuntu-120.04, mixed mode, sharing)
- javac 16.0.1

When I run `./build.sh,` I have this issue:

```
warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 6
error: Source option 6 is no longer supported. Use 7 or later.
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1853: .javac-stamp] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vhirk/go/src/github.com/test/adiitional-scripts/opentsdb/opentsdb/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1411: all] Error 2
```

I fixed this issue when I changed `source 6` -> `source 7` in the `Makefile.in`.

After this I had this issue:

```
../src/core/HistogramPojo.java:19: error: package javax.xml.bind does not exist
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
                     ^
../src/query/expression/IntersectionIterator.java:30: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException;
                                             ^
../src/query/expression/UnionIterator.java:30: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
import sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.NotImplementedException;
                                             ^
../src/tree/Branch.java:25: error: package javax.xml.bind does not exist
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
                     ^
../src/uid/UniqueId.java:309: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
  public long maxPossibleId() {
              ^
../src/uid/UniqueId.java:594: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Deferred
      final Deferred d;
            ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Deferred<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Deferred
../src/uid/UniqueId.java:1412: error: cannot find symbol
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(uid);
           ^
  symbol:   variable DatatypeConverter
  location: class UniqueId
../src/uid/UniqueId.java:1563: error: cannot find symbol
    return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(id);
           ^
  symbol:   variable DatatypeConverter
  location: class UniqueId
../src/rollup/RollupInterval.java:240: warning: [cast] redundant cast to int
    intervals = num_span / (int)interval;
                           ^
../src/core/HistogramCodecManager.java:117: warning: [deprecation] newInstance() in Class has been deprecated
        codec = (HistogramDataPointCodec) clazz.newInstance();
                                               ^
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Class
../src/core/HistogramDataPoint.java:83: warning: [overrides] Class HistogramBucket overrides equals, but neither it nor any superclass overrides hashCode method
  public class HistogramBucket implements KryoSerializable, Comparable<HistogramBucket> {
         ^
../src/core/TSSubQuery.java:287: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
  public Aggregator downsampler() {
                    ^
../src/core/TSSubQuery.java:293: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
  public long downsampleInterval() {
              ^
../src/core/TSSubQuery.java:330: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
  public Map<String, String> getTags() {
                             ^
../src/core/TSSubQuery.java:430: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
  public void setTags(Map<String, String> tags) {
              ^
../src/core/DownsamplingSpecification.java:82: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
  public DownsamplingSpecification(final long interval,
         ^
../src/core/TsdbQuery.java:651: warning: [deprecation] DownsamplingSpecification(long,Aggregator,FillPolicy) in DownsamplingSpecification has been deprecated
    this.downsampler = new DownsamplingSpecification(
                       ^
../src/core/TsdbQuery.java:1407: warning: [deprecation] DownsamplingSpecification(long,Aggregator,FillPolicy) in DownsamplingSpecification has been deprecated
              downsampler = new DownsamplingSpecification(
                            ^
../src/core/TsdbQuery.java:1777: warning: [deprecation] DownsamplingSpecification(long,Aggregator,FillPolicy) in DownsamplingSpecification has been deprecated
      downsampler = new DownsamplingSpecification(
                    ^
../src/utils/ByteSet.java:83: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
      new_set.map = (ByteMap<Object>) map.clone();
                                               ^
  required: ByteMap<Object>
  found:    Object
../src/core/Span.java:501: warning: [deprecation] Downsampler(SeekableView,long,Aggregator) in Downsampler has been deprecated
      return new Downsampler(spanIterator(), interval_ms, downsampler);
             ^
../src/core/Span.java:505: warning: [deprecation] FillingDownsampler(SeekableView,long,long,long,Aggregator,FillPolicy) in FillingDownsampler has been deprecated
      return new FillingDownsampler(spanIterator(), start_time, end_time,
             ^
../src/core/Downsampler.java:76: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
  Downsampler(final SeekableView source,
  ^
../src/core/Histogram.java:28: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Map
  public Map getHistogram();
         ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Map<K,V>
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in interface Map
    V extends Object declared in interface Map
../src/core/FillingDownsampler.java:56: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
  FillingDownsampler(final SeekableView source, final long start_time,
  ^
../src/core/HistogramPojo.java:147: error: cannot find symbol
    return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(raw);
           ^
  symbol:   variable DatatypeConverter
  location: class HistogramPojo
../src/core/HistogramPojo.java:151: error: cannot find symbol
    return DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encoded);
           ^
  symbol:   variable DatatypeConverter
  location: class HistogramPojo
../src/core/SimpleHistogram.java:250: warning: [unchecked] unchecked cast
        (Set<Map.Entry<HistogramBucket, Long>>) histo.getHistogram().entrySet()) {
                                                                             ^
  required: Set<Entry<HistogramBucket,Long>>
  found:    Set
../src/core/MultiGetQuery.java:950: warning: [cast] redundant cast to Span
      Span datapoints = (Span) spans.get(key);
                        ^
../src/core/SpanGroup.java:194: warning: [deprecation] DownsamplingSpecification(long,Aggregator,FillPolicy) in DownsamplingSpecification has been deprecated
             new DownsamplingSpecification(interval, downsampler, fill_policy) : 
             ^
../src/meta/TSUIDQuery.java:93: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
  public TSUIDQuery(final TSDB tsdb) {
         ^
../src/meta/TSUIDQuery.java:227: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
  public void setQuery(final String metric, final Map<String, String> tags) {
              ^
../src/meta/TSUIDQuery.java:551: warning: [dep-ann] deprecated item is not annotated with @Deprecated
  public static Deferred<IncomingDataPoint> getLastPoint(final TSDB tsdb, 
                                            ^
../src/query/expression/IntersectionIterator.java:448: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/query/expression/IntersectionIterator.java:453: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/query/expression/IntersectionIterator.java:458: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/query/expression/IntersectionIterator.java:463: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/query/expression/IntersectionIterator.java:483: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/query/expression/IntersectionIterator.java:488: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/query/expression/IntersectionIterator.java:493: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/query/expression/UnionIterator.java:341: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/query/expression/UnionIterator.java:360: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/query/expression/UnionIterator.java:365: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/query/expression/UnionIterator.java:370: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/query/expression/UnionIterator.java:390: warning: NotImplementedException is internal proprietary API and may be removed in a future release
    throw new NotImplementedException();
              ^
../src/tools/ConfigArgP.java:128: warning: [deprecation] reader(Class<?>) in ObjectMapper has been deprecated
      final ConfigurationItem[] loadedItems = jsonMapper.reader(ConfigurationItem[].class).readValue(configRoot);
                                                        ^
../src/tools/ConfigArgP.java:825: warning: [deprecation] reader(Class<?>) in ObjectMapper has been deprecated
          String[] jsLines = jsonMapper.reader(String[].class).readValue(bindingsNode);
                                       ^
../src/tree/Branch.java:586: error: cannot find symbol
    return DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(branch_id);
           ^
  symbol:   variable DatatypeConverter
  location: class Branch
../src/tree/Branch.java:606: error: cannot find symbol
    return DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(id);
           ^
  symbol:   variable DatatypeConverter
  location: class Branch
../src/tsd/AbstractHttpQuery.java:478: warning: [deprecation] toStringHelper(Object) in Objects has been deprecated
    return Objects.toStringHelper(this)
                  ^
../src/tsd/QueryRpc.java:430: warning: [deprecation] getLastPoint(TSDB,byte[],boolean,int,long) in TSUIDQuery has been deprecated
          deferreds.add(TSUIDQuery.getLastPoint(tsdb, entry.getKey(), 
                                  ^
../src/tsd/GraphHandler.java:198: warning: [deprecation] decode(String) in URLDecoder has been deprecated
          allow = URLDecoder.decode(allow.trim());
                            ^
../src/tsd/GraphHandler.java:239: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: HashSet
    final HashSet<String>[] aggregated_tags = new HashSet[nqueries];
                                                  ^
  missing type arguments for generic class HashSet<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in class HashSet
../src/tsd/GraphHandler.java:668: warning: [deprecation] decode(String) in URLDecoder has been deprecated
      wxh = URLDecoder.decode(wxh.trim());
                      ^
../src/tsd/GraphHandler.java:725: warning: [deprecation] decode(String) in URLDecoder has been deprecated
      given = URLDecoder.decode(given.trim());
                        ^
../src/tsd/LogsRpc.java:115: warning: [cast] redundant cast to ILoggingEvent
        final ILoggingEvent event = (ILoggingEvent) logbuf.get(nevents);
                                    ^
../src/tsd/QueryExecutor.java:854: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Map
      tags = new Map[dps.length];
                 ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Map<K,V>
  where K,V are type-variables:
    K extends Object declared in interface Map
    V extends Object declared in interface Map
../src/tsd/QueryExecutor.java:855: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: List
      agg_tags = new List[dps.length];
                     ^
  missing type arguments for generic class List<E>
  where E is a type-variable:
    E extends Object declared in interface List
../src/utils/JSON.java:214: warning: [deprecation] createJsonParser(String) in JsonFactory has been deprecated
      return jsonMapper.getFactory().createJsonParser(json);
                                    ^
../src/utils/JSON.java:236: warning: [deprecation] createJsonParser(byte[]) in JsonFactory has been deprecated
      return jsonMapper.getFactory().createJsonParser(json);
                                    ^
../src/utils/JSON.java:258: warning: [deprecation] createJsonParser(InputStream) in JsonFactory has been deprecated
      return jsonMapper.getFactory().createJsonParser(json);
                                    ^
../src/utils/PluginLoader.java:70: warning: [rawtypes] found raw type: Class
  private static final Class<?>[] PARAMETER_TYPES = new Class[] {
                                                        ^
  missing type arguments for generic class Class<T>
  where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in class Class
./src/net/opentsdb/query/expression/parser/TokenMgrError.java:110: warning: [cast] redundant cast to int
          (EOFSeen ? "<EOF> " : ("\"" + addEscapes(String.valueOf(curChar1)) + "\"") + " (" + (int)curChar + "), ") +
                                                                                              ^
9 errors
58 warnings
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1853: .javac-stamp] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/vhirk/go/src/github.com/test/adiitional-scripts/opentsdb/opentsdb/build'
make: *** [Makefile:1411: all] Error 2
```

Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

see following link:

https://github.com/OpenTSDB/opentsdb/issues/931

1- cd opentsdb-2.3.0
2- mkdir build
3- cp -r third_party ./build
4- ./build.sh